# Is there a TinyMCE plugin to remove classes from elements?

Tags: tinymce

I want to be able to remove classes from an element within the WYSIWYG editor provided by TinyMCE. I've spent some time looking around for something and haven't had any success. I've already written 4 or 5 plugins to handle different needs, but this seems to be such a basic utility, it must exist and would prefer not to have to write another plugin.

A sample use would be a paragraph that has been assigned a class using the dropdown class selector. I can continue to add classes to the paragraph element, but I can't replace them or remove them. I would like to be able to select an element in the editor and click a button to remove all assigned classes - and I want to be able to confine the function to that element node, not the entire contents (as the Remove Formatting plugin does).

```
<h4>Here is my headline</h4>
```

I use the Styles dropdown to add the class .all-caps

```
<h4 class="all-caps">Here is my headline</h4>
```

I decide I want that to use the .inverse class instead, so I select from the dropdown and end up with this:

```
<h4 class="all-caps inverse">Here is my headline</h4>
```

What I want is this:

```
<h4 class="inverse">Here is my headline</h4>
```

A plugin that will either allow me to reassign or remove classes from elements is what I need. Does anyone know of one out there?